# make: Adding function for "no rule" targets

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which uses a lot of static files, for example:

/mystaticpath/somepath/official_gpl_package-0.1.2.tar.gz

I use this Makefile on several computers and I don't need all packages on all computers. (That's the whole point of make)

Anyway, what I would like to do is put everything in /mystaticpath on a centralized server and download the packages on demand.

In other words, whenever make encounters a missing source file ("no rule"-error), it should run a script and then try again afterwards. The script would need the name of the missing file as a parameter and would download the file from the centralized server, so from make's point of view, the script is an universal creator of everything that might be needed in /mystaticpath.

Does anybody know whether that is possible with make?

Comment: Will all the "missing files" have a pattern such as `.tar.gz` or `.tar.bz2` at the end, to make it easier to write wild-card rules?

Comment: No, but all would be referenced by a fixed path, i.e. "/mystaticpath"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design makes the little hairs on the back of my neck stand up, but give this a try:

```
/mystaticpath/%:
    retrieve_script $@
```

Comment: Don't you dare to critisize my neckhair-raising designs! Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I needed :-)